# Angular Mocks Version Relation With Angular's Version

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

While implementing Karma on an AngularJS application with version `1.3.16`, the `angular-mocks` module throw the following error -

> angular-mocks.js:Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function

After googling, found that the version of Karma used i.e. `1.5.0` and the version of AngularJS are not compatible. The version of angular-mocks used is `1.6.3`.

So, after googling, found that there is no way to find out which version of AngularJS is compatible with which version of Karma or Angular-Mocks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where did you find this? Karma is just a runner, it executes tests and isn't tied to frameworks. Angular version should be matched with ngMocks version, that's all. And it was likely not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relationship is direct. They should be matched. 1.3.16 version of `angular.js` has to be matched with 1.3.16 versions of `angular-*.js` modules (including `angular-mocks.js`).

Obviously, if ngMock 1.6.3 uses a feature (`info` method) that wasn't previously implemented in core library, it will throw an error.

ngMock reference [states](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock):

> First, download the file: <...> where X.Y.Z is the AngularJS version you are running.

Angular versions aren't related to Karma versions at all. Karma is just a runner, it executes tests and isn't tied to frameworks.

Comment: Can you point to some official documentation to verify your answer?

Comment: @SahilBabbar its documented over here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/package.json

Comment: @SahilBabbar I've added some hint from the docs, but this is default behaviour for  accompanying libraries with matching versions in general. It just should be followed, unless proven otherwise.